# what should the condition in the controller to check whether solr server is running or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a recipe controller in which I have a 'create' action. In this action, whenever I am creating a recipe, it will be added to the solr immediately.

Here's my code:

```
def create

    recipe = current_user.recipes.new(params[:recipe])
    recipe_detail = recipe.build_recipe_detail
    recipe.save
    Search.add_recipe_to_solr(recipe)
    redirect_to editor_recipe_path(recipe)
  end
```

The problem is that I want to add a condition in my controller, so that it will be added to the solr **only** if the solr server is running. Otherwise it will be added to the database only, but should not throw an exception

This i the  exception when solr server is not running:

```
 Errno::ECONNREFUSED in Editor::RecipesController#create

Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Answer (score -1):

catch the exception and raise a message ,simple :)